# Are there any expenses related to managing renovations on a remote property that can be applied to increasing its cost basis?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, cost-basis

I purchased a home in another state that has needed major rehab and renovation.  I have been traveling to the location to organize, design, and monitor the numerous jobs performed by contractors (all verifiable via receipts).

While I do realize that I can not include my own *time* and contributions (*)  to increase the [*cost basis*](https://www.fool.com/millionacres/real-estate-market/home-renovations/which-home-improvements-add-your-cost-basis/), it would at least seem logical to be able to include travel expenses. But logical and *actual* only sometimes coincide: so what is the latter in this case?

(*) I was deeply involved in the design aspects of critical work including foundation repair and retaining wall construction. The results were achieving a higher "lift" and greater structural support for the foundation repair and a more appropriate retaining wall for the terrain with a longer lifetime and better drainage characteristics.   Licensed, experienced contractors performed the physical work but the costs would have been higher and the results less effective without my involvement. I do understand that my design *time* can not be included in the *cost basis* .